# Setting up authorize.net on magento payment bridge

Tags: authorize.net, payment-gateway

So I finally have MPB (magento payment bridge) installed and test transactions are submitting fine.

Now I just need help in setting it all up and learning how to take advantage of having the bridge. Can anyone help me with this? I"m new to the payment bridge world but have heard once its setup correctly I can then allow customers to save credit card data as well as having advanced options for order editing/changing/exchanging and credit memos.

Is this the case? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to setup any of this.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answers peoples questions and misconceptions about MPB. There isn't a lot of documentation and after much digging and back and forth between the Magento EE team and Authorize.net here it is:

Per Magento's EE Team:

"Unfortunately that is a misconception - Payment Bridge adds an additional layer of security to the payment information and doesn't touch it at all.

Rather, it creates and maintains a token to represent authenticated payment data saved in Authorize.net CIM, until the payment is authorized, and the token is destroyed. "

This means that anyone trying to use the MPB with auth.net has to turn on CIM for this setup to work correctly. The secure payment bridge works the same as a  gateway between the processor and Magento. Not what I thought it was for but after I try it out I will let you know how it works.

Comment: So I thought I was in the clear, I turned on CIM through auth.net now what? This is almost beginning to be not worth my time. I can't find out how and where all the added benefits of doing this are?

Comment: Not my immediate area of expertise, but it's my understanding Payment Bridge was included so Magento could reach a certain PCI compliance level.

Comment: They only added Payment Bridge so that they didn't have to put the core code itself through PCI compliance tests. Payment Bridge's development is fairly static, whereas the core is changing with each release. So they separated PB out into a separate entity, so it wouldn't need to be repeatedly tested to keep PCI approval.